# qml minus error. minus add many digit to fraction part

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

In my new Qt application, I used QML items. But in minus operator, javascript function does not subtract correctly.

When running this code:

```
console.log( "4.1 - 4 ==> " + (4.1 - 4))
```

the result is like this:

```
qml: 4.1 - 4 ==>0.09999999999999964
```

Comment: [language agnostic - Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: It's not Javascript, it's the math which is guilty. ;-) It starts with the fact that 0.1 (in decimal system) is a periodic fraction in the binary system (i.e. with an infinite number of repeating digits) which cannot be stored with a finite number of bits (except you would store it as pair of numerator and denominator).